# Windows Server 2008 R2 Server for NFS Anonymous Access

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, nfs

I have an NFS share on a Windows 2003 Server that is working perfectly with read/write access using anonymous access. I am moving to a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine and am trying to do the same. I have everything set up the same as the 2003 server and I can mount the NFS share on my linux box, but when I try to list the contents or write to it I get a "Permission Denied" message.

I have the NFS share set up to "allow anonymous access" with a -2 UID and -2 GID. I have the NFS share permissions set the ALL MACHINES read/write with no root access (the same as the 2003 server). I have the folder NTFS security set for ANONYMOUS LOGON for Full Control.

I found an article on the internet that said to give EVERYONE Full Control for NTFS security and then edit the local security policy to enable anonymous access to be in the EVERYONE group. This worked and allowed me to read/write to the NFS share, but this doesn't seem right to me. I don't want EVERYONE to have read/write access to the folder on the network. I just want to give ANONYMOUS LOGON read/write access.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Did something change in Server 2008 R2? How do I set this up?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the EVERYONE access is the recommended way. Here is a Microsoft document. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14205

Comment: Broken link :-(

Comment: i think new link is : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2485529